# Disable MFA for couple of minutes?

Tags: roles, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, privileges, multi-factor-authentication

## snowflake

Is it possible to disable MFA for couple of minutes if I'm not account admin?

If yes ... which privileges do I need to grant to specific user/role in order to get the rights to disable MFA for couple of minutes?

`ALTER USER xxx SET MINS_TO_BYPASS_MFA = 10`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you need a role that is the owner of the user.

See how to grant ownership:
https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/sql/grant-ownership.html

Privileges for reference are listed here:
https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/security-access-control-privileges.html#user-and-role-privileges

Comment: Like this? 

`GRANT OWNERSHIP ON USER xxx TO ROLE yyy;`

Comment: yepp like that ;)